# Assign App pool to site in IIS6 using c#

Tags: c#, iis-6, directoryentry

I am trying to create and assign application pool to a website in IIS6 and IIS7 using c#. I managed to do this for IIS7 `using Microsoft.Web.Administration;` but since its not supported in IIS6 i want to accomplish this using `System.DirectoryServices;`. I have managed to create the application pool but **the assigning application pool does not work**.

**Here is what I have so far...**

```
   private static string DefaultAppPool = "DefaultAppPool";
   public static void SetApplicationPoolIIS6(string websiteName)
    {
        string metabasePath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC";

        string appPoolName = GetSavedApplicationPoolName(websiteName);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appPoolName) || appPoolName.Equals(DefaultAppPool))
            appPoolName = websiteName + "AppPool";

        bool isAppPoolCreated = IsAppPoolCreatedIIS6(websiteName, appPoolName);

        if (!isAppPoolCreated)
            CreateApplicationPoolIIS6(appPoolName, metabasePath);

        DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath);
        w3svc.RefreshCache();

        foreach (DirectoryEntry item in w3svc.Children)
        {
            string siteName = item.Properties["ServerComment"].Value == null ? "" : item.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteName))
                continue;

            if (siteName.Equals(websiteName))
            {
                item.Invoke("Stop", null);
                item.Properties["AppPoolId"].Value = appPoolName;
                item.CommitChanges();
                item.Invoke("Start", null);
                break;
            }
        }

        w3svc.CommitChanges();

        DirectoryEntry w3svc2 = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath);
        w3svc2.RefreshCache();
        SaveWebSiteSettingsIIS6(websiteName, appPoolName);
    }
```

Any idea why the below lines don't assign the created app pool ?

```
item.Properties["AppPoolId"].Value = appPoolName;
item.CommitChanges();
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you're not using IIS Manager?

Comment: Doing a manual assigning to IIS between your project.. I think this is not a good idea. How about if your project need to change an IIS server PC? what will happen? Do you think your project IIS specs should be follow?